# S3 CORS for external acces

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I've hit my head against the wall with this one, hopefully it's a silly oversight that someone can help out with.

I'm using a retina jquery plugin to load retina graphics (works great BTW!); however, it is looking for files appended with "_2x" - these files exist and work great if they are hosted on our server.

The issue comes in to play with the Amazon S3, it will allow me to directly link to the file; however, when it tries to find the file with the retina suffix, it gives be this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://cloud.mfivem.com/ui/bg/bg_linen_2x.png. Origin http://beta.mfivem.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Now, the original file exists, as does the retina versions - those files are:

```
http://cloud.mfivem.com/ui/bg/bg_linen.png
http://cloud.mfivem.com/ui/bg/bg_linen_2x.png
```

I also tried the backdoor to the file:

```
http://mfivem.s3.amazonaws.com/ui/bg/bg_linen_2x.png
```

Here is my CORS file I configured for the bucket:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://test.mydomain.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

I'd really appreciate any advice, and considering the explosion of retina enabled web sites, I'm sure other members will find this helpful in the future.

Thanks for reading!

** edited URL note **

Comment: The error message says `http://beta.mfivem.com`, but your CORS config file has `<AllowedOrigin>http://test.mydomain.com</AllowedOrigin>`. Should that be `<AllowedOrigin>http://beta.mfivem.com</AllowedOrigin>`

Comment: Oh yes it is correct in my CORS file I just changed for here, but also- does the CORS file need the full domain (mfivem.com) or the domain with the cname (beta.mfivem.com)

Comment: The domain can either be the exact value, such as `http://beta.mfivem.com`, or a wildcard, such as `http://*.mfivem.com`

Comment: I've narrowed down the issue to something with cloudfront I believe, as if I try to access the file with the direct s3 bucket url it works fine. CORS file supports the access.

It's when I try to access via the CNAME that I get that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright I figured it out...

I had to add **HEAD** to the AllowedMethod, but more importantly... I had to change the names of the files and reupload them.

I think between the S3 and Cache it wasn't pulling the files correctly; however, after renaming the files, modifying the allowedmethod to include head, it works flawlessly now.

Really excited, as now I can serve up files from our custom CNAME server, masking the long and ugly s3 address using Cloudfront + S3.

Leave a comment if you're having any issues with this and I'll try to help out!